# GraphQL query error message: argument is required, but it was not provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, backend

I'm new to grapghql and my query fails.

I'm using

```
{
  product {
    id
  }
}
```

> "message": "Field "product" argument "id" of type "String!" is required, but it was not provided."

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you making a query or a mutation? It would be helpful if you could provide code that shows your request.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to code but only to its documentation, Product in documentation is written as `type Product {
id: String!
name: String!
inStock: Boolean
gallery: [String]
description: String!
category: String!
attributes: [AttributeSet]
prices: [Price!]!
brand: String!
}`

Comment: Please show us your schema. It seems to be something like `type Query { product(id: ID!): Product }` though, where `product` has a [**required** argument](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/) `id`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're making a query for a `Product` object.

GraphQL queries may require arguments, you can read more about that [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments).

The error message is telling you that field `product` requires argument `id` of type `String!`.

That means you must know the `id` of a `Product` and then can query more fields.

Let's assume there is a product with `id: "abc42"`. A query then might look like:

```
{
  product(id: "abc42") {
    name
  }
}
```

In this query the `id` is hardcoded. There are ways to pass the `id` dynamically, but that depends on your code and the libraries you are using.

Comment: what if Im looking for the whole list? In any case, it happens to be if I do something similar I get `{
  "data": {
    "product": null
  }
}`

Comment: `"product": null` means there is no `Product` with the `id` that you provided.

Comment: If you're looking for the whole list of products, you should check if there is a query like `products` (plural) or something similar. Right now you query `product` (singular).